# Why does homebrew link to ../Cellar and not /usr/local/Cellar?

Tags: macos, maven, homebrew

I have:

- MacOS 10.12.2
- homebrew 1.1.5
- maven 2.0.8

I am trying to install maven 3

before running brew, `which mvn` reports `/usr/local/apache-maven-2.0.8/bin/mvn` as we would expect.

after running `brew install maven` without errors `which mvn` now reports `../Cellar/maven/3.3.9/bin/mvn` and `mvn -v` still reports 2.0.8.

I'm new to brew. `brew doctor` does not report any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting `/usr/local/bin` first on your PATH with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Because users might install Homebrew in a different path (e.g. `~/.homebrew`). In order to support any install path Homebrew uses relative paths when symlinking binaries and other files.

> after running `brew install maven` without errors `which mvn` now reports `../Cellar/maven/3.3.9/bin/mvn` and `mvn -v` still reports 2.0.8.

This is a different issue; this time due to your shell which checks the full path of an executable only the first time you use it. That is, the first time you typed `mvn -v` it did the equivalent of `which mvn` and remembered that path. The second time you typed `mvn -v` it used that path instead of re-checking it. Type `hash -r` to reset its memory or start a new shell.